# Невозможно определить похожесть двух поисковых выдач

Tags: elasticsearch

Я хочу нормировать скалярное произведение при ранжировании.

Объясню простыми словами, а потом добавлю чуть-чуть математики. Пусть у нас есть 2 поисковые выдачи. Одна поисковая выдача сформирована для запроса `Пупкины сыновья`, а вторая -- для запроса `Сыновья Пупкины`. Тогда имеем выдачу:

```
document_0, score_0
document_1, score_1
document_2, score_2
...
document_p, score_p
```

Выдача для второго запроса:

```
document_0, score_0
document_1, score_1
document_2, score_2
...
document_q, score_q
```

Пусть score_0 для первой выдачи равен 500. А score для второй выдачи равен 0.5. Задача требуется уметь сравнивать скоры различных выдач и оценивать релевантность друг относительно друга.

По умолчанию функция ранжирования, насколько я знаю, является скалярным произведением. Например, у нас есть вектор для запроса `(v)` и вектор для документов `(d_i)`. Для ранжирования мы делаем `(q, d_i)` для всех `i`, где `(., .)` - скалярное произведение. Пожалуйста, объясните мне, можно ли рассчитать `(q / | q |, d_i / | d_i |)`? Мне кажется, что если решение и существует, возможно три решения моей проблемы.

- `function_score`. Могу ли я получить вес (tf-idf) в `function_score`?
- получение всех весов с помощью API elasticsearch. Флаг `explain` не подходит так как с ним запрос будет обрабатываться крайне долго. Другая сторона отрицательная сторона `explain` -- возврат пересечения (токены `q` и `d_i`). Обратите внимание: хотя сейчас я говорю о точечном произведении, в будущем я хочу вычислить евклидово расстояние.
- нормализовать веса поиска по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, это невозможно сделать. Единственный вариант, который мне предложили -- это пропатчить эластик. Но данный вариант не выглядит адекватным, так как это придётся переделывать после любого обновления версии. Это больно. Скрипты не позволяют добраться до весов. Плагины -- аналогично.

Объясняется это скорее всего тем, эластик распределённый и не все веса хранятся на одном шарде.